# Why is mongoose.find returning an empty Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating an express server in which I am trying to find the tracks in my database. Even though I have created the model to exactly how the attributes are in my database it still returns me an empty array. Please help

**app.js**

```
require('./config/config');
require('./db');
var Track = require('./models/track.model');

const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      express = require('express'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();


const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', () => {
      console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully!');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
      Track.find({}, function(err, tracks) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(tracks);
                process.exit();
            }
            else {
                throw err;
            }
        }); 
      res.sendFile('index.html', {root: __dirname});
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=> console.log(`Server started at port: ${process.env.PORT}`));
```

**track.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Track = new Schema({
  Position: {
    type: Number
  },
  Track: {
    type: String
  },
  Artist: {
    type: String
  },
  Streams: {
    type: Number
  },
  Url: {
    type: String
  },
  Date: {
    type: String
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Track', Track);
```

[image: Track Collection]

Comment: Are you *actually* connecting to mongo database? `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {useNewUrlParser: true});` seems missing in your code.

Comment: yes I required **db.js** which reads ```const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true},  (err) => {
    if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB connection succeeded.'); }
    else { console.log('Error in MongoDB connection : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
});```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind Schema to collection like this:

```
let Track = new Schema({
  Position: {
    type: Number
  },
  Track: {
    type: String
  },
  Artist: {
    type: String
  },
  Streams: {
    type: Number
  },
  Url: {
    type: String
  },
  Date: {
    type: String
  }
}, { collection : 'spotifyCharts' });
```

Comment: still get an empty array

Comment: It should be { collection : 'spotifyCha**r**ts' }. Syntax error there.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!err){

     console.log(tracks);

     //Convert to JSON format

     res.json(tracks)

     process.exit();

   }
```

2.

Test along with `Collection Name` in `module.exports`

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Track', Track, 'CollectionName')
```